# How to place an img behind a card and make it responsive

Tags: html, css

### I would like to put an image behind a card and make it responsive

Quite useless to share my code because i really don't know where to go with this problem.
I already tried to put the img in a `:after` or `:before` but i could't manage to make it not break the `display:flex` of the card container, i tried to put it in the card using `z-index` but it creates a blank space before the text.
So i tried to schematize what i would like to do, **thanks a lot!** :) 
[Ugly drawing of what i want :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYf5D.png)

Comment: Use position relative on the parent element that contains the image and text content elements. Then set the position of the image to absolute. Then you can control the left, right, top, bottom and z-index properties of the positioned element.

Comment: Also your question will get closed if you do not add proper code to reproduce your issue, further more as the community you will likely get a negative vote on answers to questions that do not have code provided as this is a sight controlled by community and many think people should not bother with questions that do not follow the laid out guidlines and they downvote answers on questions without provided reproducible code added... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok sorry i'll be more careful later about this, this was my first question and i understand that i should follow the rules, deeply sorry ! :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use position relative to the parent and position absolute to the image which you want to place behind and adjust the top and bottom values

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/haribabu-manoharan/pen/Popzagm%27)

```css
.main-row>div{
  background-color: #ffd5ff;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.main-row p::first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.main-row .smily {
  position:absolute;
  top:-35px;
  left:-35px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div class="container">
  <div class="row main-row d-flex text-justify mt-5 d-flex justify-content-between position-relative">
    <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/smiley_PNG155.png" style="height:60px; width:auto;" class="smily">
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 para1 p-4 shadow mb-4">    
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, rem ratione deserunt necessitatibus ducimus excepturi quisquam hic, eum esse dignissimos laboriosam assumenda sapiente voluptas fugiat nulla inventore repellat consequuntur quasi?
    Soluta mollitia voluptatibus molestiae, magnam rerum accusamus veritatis minima totam veniam! Incidunt ratione cupiditate quia aspernatur excepturi sit dolorum, fugit harum officia hic quam beatae itaque pariatur atque! Deserunt, provident.</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 para2 p-4 shadow mb-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, rem ratione deserunt necessitatibus ducimus excepturi quisquam hic, eum esse dignissimos laboriosam assumenda sapiente voluptas fugiat nulla inventore repellat consequuntur quasi?
    Soluta mollitia voluptatibus molestiae, magnam rerum accusamus veritatis minima totam veniam! Incidunt ratione cupiditate quia aspernatur excepturi sit dolorum, fugit harum officia hic quam beatae itaque pariatur atque! Deserunt, provident.</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 para3 p-4 shadow mb-4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, rem ratione deserunt necessitatibus ducimus excepturi quisquam hic, eum esse dignissimos laboriosam assumenda sapiente voluptas fugiat nulla inventore repellat consequuntur quasi?
    Soluta mollitia voluptatibus molestiae, magnam rerum accusamus veritatis minima totam veniam! Incidunt ratione cupiditate quia aspernatur excepturi sit dolorum, fugit harum officia hic quam beatae itaque pariatur atque! Deserunt, provident.</p></div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  
<a class="mx-auto mt-4" href="https://www.neramclasses.com"><strong>show some love by adding this link to your website as a credit</strong></a></div></div>






 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

'